# Retrieving timestamp from opentsdb

Tags: timestamp, opentsdb

I am trying to retrieve data from opentsdb and trying to display in graphs. I am not getting full timestamp (here time in millisec). I am getting 10gidits only last 3 numbers are getting truncated. Any idea on how to solve this... 
I am referring this [link](https://github.com/CardioVascular-Research-Group/cvrg-opentsdb-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under **Times** in http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/index.html

```
... Unless a down sampling algorithm has been specified with a query, the data will automatically be down sampled to 1 second using the same aggregation function specified in a query. ...
```

Can you try specifying a downsampling time period of 1ms?